# How to create the effect of stacking and religning divs in javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Assume I have a single div with two buttons to add box and remove box:

```
<div id="container" height=500 width=300>
</div>
<button>Add</button>
<button>Remove</button>
```

Clicking on Add would "add" a div to the container of width "200" and height= "200" with the letter "X". Clicking on "add" a second time would add a box of the same size right above it.

Clicking on any of the "X" on a div would cause the div to disappear and the other divs below it would slide up to fill its space.

Clicking on remove would remove the top box and cause any other divs below to slide up to take its space.

How to accomplish this effect in Javascript?

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) effect can be used to hide a div and slide the other ones together

For a more advanced library, have a look at [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html)

Comment: If possible I would prefer not to use an advanced library. Could you demonstrate an example of the slidetoggle in the context of my question?